# Adding Span with Class to a input tag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add a Span after my Input that will have the class "error" and the text "test".

I've tried the append, and insertAfter methods. I can get the code to work on jsfiddle but I cannot get the code to work on my application.

I have put the HTML and JS/Jquery below. My end result would have a Span (with the class error) next to each input with the type text. I would then set a value for this span based on a validation loop.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Zito - Lab 7</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="reservation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
    <form action="response.html" method="get"
          name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>General Information</legend>
            <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date" autofocus><br>
            <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
            <label>Adults:</label>
            <select name="adults" id="adults">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select><br>
            <label>Children:</label>
            <select name="children" id="children">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select><br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Preferences</legend>
            <label>Room type:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" class="left" checked>Standard&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" class="left">Business&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" class="left last">Suite<br>
            <label>Bed type:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" class="left" checked>King&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" class="left last">Double Double<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking">Smoking<br>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Contact Information</legend>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="999-999-9999"><br>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Request"><br>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS/JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;
var phonePattern = /\b(\d{3})([-])(\d{3})([-])(\d{4})\b/;
var datePattern =  /\b(0[1-9]|1[012])([/])(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])([/])((20)\d\d)\b/;

$(":text").after("<span class='error'>*</span>");
$("#arrival_date").focus();

$("#reservation_form").submit(
    function(event) {
        var isValid = true;

        // validate arrival date
        var arrivalDate = $("#arrival_date").val();
        if (arrivalDate == "") {
            $("#arrival_date").next().text("This field is required");
            isValid = false;
        } else if (!datePattern.test(arrivalDate)) {
            $("#arrival_date").next().text("Must be in the format 12/12/2012");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#arrival_date").next().text("");
        }

        // validate nights
        var nights = $("#nights").val();
        if (nights == "") {
            $("#nights").next().text("This field is required");
            isValid = false;
        } else if ((isNaN(parseInt(nights))) || (parseInt(nights) <=0)) {
            $("#nights").next().text("This field must be a number and not zero");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#nights").next().text("");
        }

        // validate name
        var name = $("#name").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $("#name").next().text("This field is required");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#name").next().text("");
        }

        // validate email
        var email = $("#email").val();
        if (email == "") {
            $("#email").next().text("This field is required");
            isValid = false;
        } else if (!emailPattern.test(email) ) {
            $("#email").next().text("Must be a valid email address.");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#email").next().text("");
        }

        // validate phone
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        if (phone == "") {
            $("#phone").next().text("This field is required");
            isValid = false;
        } else if (!phonePattern.test(phone) ) {
            $("#phone").next().text("Must be in the format 999-999-9999");
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $("#phone").next().text("");
        }


        if (isValid == false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#arrival_date").focus();
        }
    }
);


}); // end ready
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question? I've uploaded it to my FTP site and it wont work there. http://www.dsu-class.com/zito82/lab07/

Comment: EXACTLY, I can't figure out why it is not rendering on the site though?

Comment: Cut it down to code referenced above and its still not working

Comment: Can you try on your live site since the fiddle works fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xebzdep6/?

Comment: Yep, trying on the site and it's not working. Not sure if I should delete the question and repost. It seems the error is not with the code but is with something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most easy way is to add a Div container around the form and just append the warning to that. To effectively append after an element you need to give it a class or id.

```
var email = $("#email"); //using class instead of input:text
var html = "<span class='error'>TEST!</span>"
email.after( html );
```

But I personally would like something like this better:

```
var generateError = function(){
var html = "<div id='error' style='top: 0; left:0; width:100%; height: 50px; background-color: red; text-allign: center; display:none; z-index: 100;'> ERROR!!</div>"
$(body).append( html );
}

var showError = function( text ){
var err = $("#error");
err.html( text );
err.show(500).delay(2000).hide(500); 
}
```

Code is fairly self-explaining, but this will make two functions: generateError and showError. 
generateError you need to call before you want to show the error, possibly when the page loads it will add a small header on top of all you other elements and will appear hidden. 
showError uses a text argument with the error you want to show. Then it will set the text to the div and show it for two seconds.

---

This then is more what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input = $("input");
    var emailPattern = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b/;

    input.keypress(function (ele) {
        // if regex.test( input ) === false
        createErrors(ele.target);
    })
});

var createErrors = function (ele) {
    $('<span>TEST!</span>').insertAfter(ele);

    $("#arrival_date").focus();
};
```

This works on keypress, that means the regex gets checked every time a key is pressed. It also passes the element where the user is typing as parameter, this means that you wont get errors for all input:text, but only for the ones where there is an error.

[Updated Fiddle (still not perfect, but if its an school exercise this will help you to finish it :)](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xebzdep6/)

Comment: Why is this necessary when the fiddle shows that the code already works?

Comment: Read the comments below the question.

Comment: No offense but then is my solution still a better option because the fiddle shows error behind EVERY input, while it should only show at the ones where a mistake/error has been made. My solution is then also not complete because I dont check...

Comment: I know there are better ways but this is a school lab so i have to follow the instructions.

Comment: Updated my answer, this should probably help you better :)

Comment: Ended up being a browser cache issue that was keeping the JQuery from loading.